# Wordpress can't update when using reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have install Wordpress from the official docker image using this configuration.

```
services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 192.168.1.20
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - /sites/wp:/var/www/html
```

The site is working fine either using port 9000 directrly or using reverse proxy.
The problem is that when I'm using reverse proxy (tried both apache & nginx) I can't install any plugin or theme.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.
```

Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 183 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php:183) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your external port 80 if you use port 9000 as a proxy? Port 80 should work on a container with Apache or Nginx which is served by the Front-end

Comment: Please do not post your comments as answer.